# how to create domain from databace view from grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I tried to create domain class from database view. But when I try run project I see:

> Error |
>       2016-01-19 17:15:00,525 [Thread-11] ERROR spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - ORA-    01702: a view is not appropriate here
>       Error |
>       2016-01-19 17:15:00,526 [Thread-11] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - HHH000299: Could not complete schema update

my class:

```
class Branch {

int id
String name

    static mapping = {
        table 'smart_branch'
        version false
        cache: 'read-only'
        id column: 'id'
        name column: 'name'
    }

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

I use oracle 10g and in the view I use link to another oracle database.

view:

```
create or replace view branch (id, name) as (select id, convert(zzz.convert2@b(name)) from zzz.branch@db emp)
```

Answer (score 1):

Domain class is an entity, a table inside db on which you can run DML queries. Views are mainly used for only fetching the data and not modifying it.

You should also not try that. Also if you are using Hibernate to generate schema for you, then you can't have a table and a view with same name. You would have to either set `dbCreate` mode to `none` in your `DataSource.groovy` or remove the mapping of the doamin from db using `mapWith` property.

But if you still want to have a Doamin class that fetches data from a view then you can look into this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34046713/1799527).

Comment: I don't want insert or update in the view. I need this class for relation whit another domain. I tried mapWith property, but when I use class 'Branch' in another domain I see: caused by MappingException: An association from the table ZZZZ refers to an unmapped class: Branch

Comment: You cann't do that. You can have other other domains as properties within Branch domain but not Branch domain as a property in other domains

Comment: I do it. and this works. but when I run project I see that errors. and some changes in all domain classes do not updated in the database. and this causes some inconvenience